# ¿Cómo encender un LED a través de raspberry python y un PC en red local?

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

La idea de esta pregunta es saber cómo, a través de un script de python en ubuntu, enviar una señal a una raspberry conectada en red local y que ésta, a su vez, encienda un LED.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: He estado investigando y esto se puede hacer a traves de un socket TCP, alguien tiene algún ejemplo para guiarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible forma de hacerlo es con sockets.

Yo usaría sockets UDP si se trata de una red local, pues hay muy baja probabilidad de que los paquetes se pierdan en este tipo de red y es más sencillo implementar la lógica del servidor porque no tienes que preocuparte de mantener la conexión abierta o cerrarla, simplificando así la aplicación.

Éste sería un ejemplo:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # Crear el socket udp
s.bind(("", 55555))                                   # Ponerle un número de puerto

while True:  # Bucle infinito, se repite por siempre
    mensaje, _ = s.recvfrom(1000)  # 1000 es el tamaño máximo esperado, no importa mucho el número
    print("Recibido: {}".format(mensaje))
    if b"ENCENDER" in mensaje:
        encender_led()
    # No hay más, repetimos el bucle para esperar otro mensaje
```

En la raspberry ejecutas el script anterior con python 3. Se quedará a la espera de mensajes en el puerto 55555. Cuando reciba uno, lo imprimirá por pantalla (en bytes) y si contiene el texto "ENCENDER", llamará a la función `encender_led()`, que ya tendrías que programar tú.

Para enviarle un mensaje desde el PC puedes programar otro script en python que de forma similar cree un socket (no necesitas hacer `bind()` en este caso) y le envíe el comando con una línea como:

```
s.sendto(b"ENCENDER", ("192.168.1.103", 55555))
```

Donde `"192.168.1.103"` sería la IP de la raspberry y 55555 el puerto en que está escuchando el script anterior.

Pero ni siquiera necesitas escribir este script en el lado Ubuntu. Puedes usar la herramienta `nc` que permite enviar mensajes por TCP o UDP a cualquier máquina, por ejemplo escribiendo lo siguiente en una terminal:

```
$ echo "ENCENDER" | nc -u 192.168.1.103 55555
```

La opción `-u` es para que use UDP, y el resto serían la IP y puerto en que está esperando el mensaje la raspberry.

Comment: Excelente @abulafia respuesta precisa y muy bien explicada. Muchas gracias.